# Why does the Brickset inventory page incorrectly list a set as including 200 of a part when it actually includes more?

Tags: inventory

One example of this issue would be a set like [42056](https://brickset.com/sets/42056-1/Porsche-911-GT3-RS) that has 516 black Technic pins with friction. Brickset lists it as only having 200. Is this a technical limitation of some kind? What causes this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with database limitations or anything like that. Brickset scrapes their inventories from the replacement parts list on LEGO.com:

https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/replacementparts

Normally, you are able to request as many replacement parts as there are parts in the set, so this is the number that Brickset uses for it's inventory count. Unfortunately, the max you can request is 200, so Brickset doesn't list more than 200 of the same part being found in a set.

Comment: That's a fun bug.  Can we fix those quantities after they scrape it?

Comment: I believe that they intentionally keep this data synced directly with what is found on lego.com. They do also link to curated inventories (Bricklink, Rebrickable, etc). From their contact page: "Information about parts and set inventories comes from LEGO customer services we are unable to make changes to it." I'll ping their staff about this just in case.

Comment: Thank you -- that is exactly why. We don't modify inventories once obtained, we prefer to keep them verbatim, errors and all. -- Huw, Brickset.com

Comment: @HuwMillington Makes sense. Thanks for the info!