# Is there a list of the most common Lego Technic parts?

Tags: technic

I searched the internet for this and I found a list of complete sets. But I am looking for a list of the most common (and in some sense the most important or most helpful) individual Lego Technic parts. Is this available somewhere?

Comment: I'm guessing that this would probably be the Technic Pegs (with or without the friction nubs), as most Technic sets include a fair number of them to join things together, followed by axles and cogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Brickset, you can browse parts in the technic subcategory and you can  sort by "Set count", i.e. the number of sets the element appears in.

https://brickset.com/parts/category-Technic

So that would take care of your "most common" requirement. I'm afraid that "most important" or "helpful" is rather subjective and hence difficult to quantify and have lists sorted by those measures...

Comment: Big +1 for solution that works for "most common" anything and likely will not get outdated.

Comment: And then you also need to click through to sort by "number in each set" - for example the "Connector Peg with Friction" not only comes in the most sets (almost 1900 at the time of writing), but it's also in very large quantities, the first 30 or so results contain [at least 200 of them](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/9222/56).

Comment: 724 in the bucket wheel excavator, you can use bricklink for an accurate part count, it doesn't source its inventories from the lego replacement pages, they're done manually.
We should take into account the nature of this element though; it's THE pin, it's how you connect things with technic, basically having the same function as studs in system lego...